# add_post_type_support but for front_page only

Tags: php

I want to enable excerpt for pages, but for front_page only.
Using `add_post_type_support('page','excerpt')` enables it for all pages, since the first argument is `$post_type`.
How can I narrow down it to front_page? Various ifs in functions.php like `is_front_page()` doesn't work since I've read Wordpress, on `functions.php` loading, doesn't know yet about post types.

Prefer not to use css to hide excerpt field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable excerpt for specific page, then you can add some conditions to narrow down.

For check "front page id" you can use `get_option('page_on_front');` in admin area. (`is_front_page()` should not work here)

```
global $pagenow;
// check current screen is edit page 
if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
    $fron_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    $current_page = $_GET['post'];
    // check current page is match with front page
    if($fron_page_id == $current_page){
        add_post_type_support('page','excerpt');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just great, works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @qfwfq . Glad to help. If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer. It will helps others find it as resolved.